# How to call a function on a click on a component?

Tags: javascript, click, components

```
function component(width, height, source, x, y) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = source;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;  
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
            this.x, 
            this.y,
            this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function(a, b, image, h) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
        this.image.src = image;
        this.height = h;
    }
}
```

How do I call a function when a click is done on the component?
Or should I just record the coordinates of the click and compare them with the ones of he component?

Answer (score 0):

When working with HTML5 Canvas, there are unfortunately no individual nodes where you can register a click event. Your only real option here is to register a click event on the `<canvas>` element itself and then use the X and Y coordinates to figure out what component was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are using vanilla JS or an special engine, but if you can use JQuery, maybe you must take look at this https://api.jquery.com/click/, it allows you to execute a function every time your component is clicked
The code below is only an example about how the function could be use, test it to be sure this works for you

```
    function component(width, height, source, x, y) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = source;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;  
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
            this.x, 
            this.y,
            this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function(a, b, image, h) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
        this.image.src = image;
        this.height = h;
    }
    $(this).click(function(){
        //Code here
    });
}
```